# Can't Boot Ubuntu Virtual Machine on Azure

Tags: ubuntu, azure

I have a virtual machine I use for testing.  I last booted it two weeks ago and ran the standard aptitude safe-upgrade on it then shut it down.  I just tied to boot the virtual machine today (July 8th) and I'm getting the following error:

> No version found in the artifact repository that satisfies the requested version '2.0' for VM extension with publisher 'Microsoft.OSTCExtensions' and type 'LinuxDiagnostic'.

I get the same error if I try to redeploy and resize the VM.  The virtual machine was setup using the Resource Manager (a non-classic VM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by deleting the Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.LinuxDiagnostic extension.  The steps I took where:

1. Start the VM even though it says there was an error.  If I tired to remove the extension before starting the VM I got the following error:

   Failed to delete the virtual machine extension 'Microsoft.Insights.VMDiagnosticsSettings'. Error: OperationNotAllowed: Cannot modify extensions in the VM when the VM is not running.

   When starting the VM I still got the original error message:

   Failed to start virtual machine 'some-vm'. Error: No version found in the artifact repository that satisfies the requested version '2.0' for VM extension with publisher 'Microsoft.OSTCExtensions' and type 'LinuxDiagnostic'.
2. Once the VM is started delete the extension via the Azure website in the Extensions menu.  Then click the uninstall.  The uninstall can take a couple minutes, let it do it's thing.  In my case I also deleted the VMAccessForLinux Extension.

[image: Removing Azure Extensions]

3. I stopped the VM then restarted it and now I can SSH into it.

Thanks to Ryan for his tip about removing diagnostics.  That lead me on the correct path of deleting the extension.  GordonB, I thought about having the delete the VM and re-create it but that was my last resort option.

I didn't install these extensions, I'm assuming they where installed when I created the VM a year or so ago.  Does anyone have any idea why the extensions suddenly stopped working?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try going into the virtual machine settings and then diagnostics, turn diagnostics off. If that doesn't let the machine boot then google how to use powershell or azure cli to login to azure and then remove the extension. Once the extension is removed you can then reboot the machine and turn diagnostics back on.

Answer (score 0):

*edit* I just realized you weren't just trying to resize you were trying to boot, my apologies. This will only work for machines that won't shut down or reboot.

Try to restart the waagent service according to the following article. If that doesn't work you may need to try to install the waagent manually to ensure you have the correct version.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-update-agent/

Comment: Instead of a 2nd answer prefaced with "*edit*", you could have actually edited your original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the vm, create another with the same disks. Worth a shot.

Comment: This is, at best, a comment. Doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Unless of course it does solve his provlen